# String.format vs StringBuilder vs String.Concat vs string + string

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net, string, concat

Estoy realizando un `log` en .Net el cual antes y después de cada proceso se llenará un `string` con el mensaje:

```
"proceso x realizado \n"
"proceso y saltado \n" //porque o se realiza x o y 
"proceso a fallo al sumar \n"
"proceso n [...] \n"
```

Cada mensaje se agrega al `string` después de cada proceso con todos los mensajes que este tenga.

Como aparece en el título hay varias formas de crear un `string` de este tipo.

A lo que mi pregunta es, cual de las formas de crear un `string` es la que consume menos recursos o es más eficiente.

Cabe destacar que el `string` final al menos tendrá 25 líneas

Comment: Si esto funciona como en java esa seria StringBuider ya que las otras 3 son cadenas ESTATICAS a las que se les da formato o se concatenan. La referencia de la cadena es reemplazada por otra con el mismo nombre, y la anterior cadena no se destruye solo queda libre para que la recoja el garbage colector. En cambio StringBuilder es una cadena dinámica que va pidiendo memoria o liberando memoria, según se hace chica o grande y usa siempre una sola referencia, por lo que es la que rinde mejor (aunque todo esto es si c# funciona como java, lo cual desconozco).

Comment: La respuesta depende del código que usas, y esa parte no la has incluído, aunque lo cierto es que usar `StringBuilder` rara vez es mala idea. Así que, hasta que no compartas tu código, no queda claro si hay en realidad una mejor manera adecuada para tu caso.

Comment: La respuesta de @Flxtr es muy completa y aclara todas tus dudas. De todas maneras, hablamos de una microoptimización, es decir, utilices el método que utilices la diferencia será practicamente inapreciable, asi que yo te recomendaría que uses el método con el que estes mas comodo o te resulte mas legible.

Comment: ¿El sistema de log va a tener niveles? Porque lo primero sería un método que comprueba si el mensaje de log va a ser usado (p.ej., si configuras el log para INFO los mensajes de nivel DEBUG no se muestran, con lo cual te puedes ahorrar todo el proceso de formación del mensaje).

Comment: Era un log informativo mas que nada para indicar al usuario en pantalla que fue lo que fallo, ya que muchos de los procesos son asíncronos, por lo que se el log se llena con la informacion de inicio, fallo o fin de cada proceso realizado. por eso queria saber que tipo de construccion de string era el mejor. pero ya fue resuelto. Gracias

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Para el caso de **C#**:

## `String.Format` internamente utiliza `StringBuilder`:

```
public static string Format(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args)
{
    if ((format == null) || (args == null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException((format == null) ? "format" : "args");
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(format.Length + (args.Length * 8));
    builder.AppendFormat(provider, format, args);
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

## Operador `+` se convierte en `String.Concat`

Cuando tenemos este ejemplo de código:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = "there";
string z = "chaps";
string all = x + y + z;
```

Al momento de compilarlo se convierte en:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = "there";
string z = "chaps";
string all = string.Concat(x, y, z);
```

La [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) dice:

> Una operación de concatenación de objeto `String` siempre crea un nuevo objeto a partir de la cadena existente y los nuevos datos. Un objeto `StringBuilder` mantiene un búfer para acomodar la concatenación de nuevos datos. Los nuevos datos se añaden al búfer si hay espacio disponible; De lo contrario, se asigna un nuevo búfer más grande, se copian los datos del búfer original en el nuevo búfer y se añaden los nuevos datos al nuevo búfer.

Por lo tanto:

> La ejecución de una operación de concatenación para un objeto `String` o `StringBuilder` depende de la frecuencia de las asignaciones de memoria.

(Ahora cobra sentido [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17615/3200493) de [samjudson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908/samjudson), donde menciona que la primer ejecución y el orden importan y siempre tardarán más tiempo)

## En resumen

Depende del objetivo de tu prueba, ya que a final de cuentas el formato que des a tu `String` también consume recursos, ya que no es lo mismo agrear una simple cadena que agregar una cadena que tiene algún formato en específico (en este caso sería `StringBuilder.Append()` contra `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()`). Algunas personas basan la técnica a utilizar conforme al [número de elementos que usan en ese momento](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1612819/3200493). Al igual que un `StringBuilder` tiene muchas más funcionalidades que simplemente la concatenación.

**¿Cuál deberás elegir?** La respuesta es depende. Para tu caso expuesto sugiero utilizar **`String.Concat`**, para casos más detallados lo mejor sería `StringBuilder`.

Referencias:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/306822/how-to-improve-string-concatenation-performance-in-visual-c
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785/is-string-format-as-efficient-as-stringbuilder
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10341208/3200493
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17615/3200493
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1787696/3200493
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1612819/3200493
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-strings

Answer (score 0):

La manera más eficiente de crear una cadena de caracteres a partir de la concatenación de otras cadenas es utilizando la clase `StringBuilder`, cuyo objetivo como su nombre en inglés indica es la construcción de objetos `String`.